# Expected String or Byte Object, Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was working on creating a machine learning model using tensorflow (MNIST DATASET). The model got trained perfectly but there is an error arising while making the predictions.
The Problem is that I am unable to identify the mistake, I haven't used any kind of string or byte object which is showing the error.
Also, do let me know whether I am moving into the right direction while creating the neural network or not.

This is Regarding the `MNIST` Dataset.

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

input_data_train=pd.read_csv('fashion-mnist_train.csv')
y_train=input_data_train['label']
x_train=input_data_train.drop(columns=['label'])

y_train=np.array(y_train)
y_train=y_train.reshape(-1,1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
y_train=enc.fit_transform(y_train)

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
'''since we will be using tensor flow as framework for the creation of 
the neural network'''
'''since it is a convention that the input layer is designed on the a 
placeholder and the perpetual hidden layers on the variable'''
input_layer_x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,784))
input_layer_y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,10))
w1=tf.get_variable('wq',[784,50])
b1=tf.get_variable('bq',[50])
'''generating the outputs'''
output_1=tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(input_layer_x,w1),b1))

'''now we will move towards the second layer'''
w2=tf.get_variable('wa',[50,25])
b2=tf.get_variable('ba',[25])
output_2=tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(output_1,w2),b2))

'''now we will be moving towards out output layer'''
w3=tf.get_variable('wz',[25,10])
b3=tf.get_variable('bz',[10])
output_3=tf.add(tf.matmul(output_2,w3),b3)

'''we have now defined all our layers and output layer'''
'''moving towards using the cost function'''

  cost= tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with
       _logits_v2(logits=output_ 
        3,labels=input_layer_y))




 opt=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
 batch_size=10000
 epochs=5
 init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
 ''' this helped to initialise all the values '''
 sess.run(init) 

 i=0
 j=0
 while i<epochs:

 j=0
 while j<60000:
    start=j*batch_size
    batch_x=x_train[start:start +batch_size]
    batch_y=y_train[start:start +batch_size]
    a,res= sess.run([opt,cost],feed_dict={input_layer_x:batch_x,input_layer_y:batch_y})
    j=j+1
i=i+1
print(i)
'''now since out model is trained we will be testing this with respect to 
our inputs(training)'''

data_test=pd.read_csv('fashion-mnist_test.csv')
y_test=input_data_train['label']
x_test=input_data_train.drop(columns=['label'])

y_test=np.array(y_test)
y_test=y_test.reshape(-1,1)
y_test=enc.fit_transform(y_test)




pred=tf.equal(tf.math.argmax(output_3,1),tf.math.argmax(input_layer_y),1)
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(pred,tf.float32))
sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={X:x_test,Y:y_test})
''' now we will be looking towards the accuracy '''

sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code above. Follow below steps to get rid of any error:

- Replace `pred = tf.equal(tf.math.argmax(output_3,1),tf.math.argmax(input_layer_y),1)` to `pred = tf.equal(tf.math.argmax(output_3, 1), tf.math.argmax(input_layer_y, 1))`
- There are no placeholders named `X` and `Y` in above code. So, replace `sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={X:x_test,Y:y_test})` to `sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={input_layer_x:x_test,input_layer_y:y_test})` as `input_layer_x` and `input_layer_y` are the valid placeholders used above.
- Instead of using `fit_transform` method on test label, you should apply your already fitted `enc` by just the `transform` method like below:

  `y_test=enc.transform(y_test)`